# Using VB6 & Janus Gridex - Anyone know how to highlight a single cell value?

Tags: vb6, janus, gridex

Seems Janus doesn't think a developer might have a need to highlight the value of a single cell for the user...

It appears the SelStart & SelLength properties apply to the entire grid(wtf?)

I need to show a grid, and when the user enters the desired cell, to highlight the value for them for editing.. You know, highlight the value, start typing replaces the current value...

Should be like a simple txtBox.SelStart=0 & txtBox.SelLength=len(txtBox), But NO!!! Janus is WAY to smart for that...

Anyone out there smarter than Janus?  Help!!

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
GridEX1.SetFocus
GridEX1.Row = 2
GridEX1.Col = 3
GridEX1.EditMode = jgexEditModeOn
GridEX1.SelStart = 0
GridEX1.SelLength = 1000
```